# Convert + to 00 for international calling

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, calls, google-voice, international-prefix

I am currently overseas, using a foreign SIM card in my phone. Since I travel often, all of my contacts are stored in international format (e.g. +12125551212 or +4474567899). However, my foreign carrier does not allow international dialing via +countrycode (i.e. +1), only via 00countrycode (i.e. 001).

Additionally, I had thought I would be able to use Google Voice for my calls back to the U.S. and therefore have my Google Voice caller ID show on outbound calls, but Google Voice also dials the access number via +countrycode so the call fails as well.

Is there any way to set my phone to automatically dial 00 instead of the + without having to modify all of my contacts?

**Edit:** I just noticed there are several apps that do this. If anyone knows of a native solution, please reply.

**Edit 2:** I just tried a couple of these apps. While they do work, when I try to use them with Google Voice, they replace the + prefix for the destination number, not the Google Voice access number. I need a way to have Google Voice dial its access number with 001 instead of +1.

Answer (score 1):

Log into your Google account and click on contacts. Then select all your contacts.

Now click on more => export => select all contacts => export format Google CSV.

Use the "find and replace" option in for instance Excel to edit from +385 to 00385.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but I think... only if totally necessary, after trying all other answers... unless you just don't care... Try to wipe the phone so that you go through first boot and setup again, and it should use GPS to dialing prefix.